# Extract Acronyms and Māori (non-english) words in a dataframe, and put them in adjacent columns within the dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, nlp, acronym

Regular expression seems a steep learning curve for me. I have a dataframe that contains texts (up to 300,000 rows). The text as contained in `outcome` column of a dummy file named `foo_df.csv` has a mixture of English words, acronyms and Māori words. `foo_df.csv` is as thus:

```
    outcome
0   I want to go to DHB
1   Self Determination and Self-Management Rangatiratanga
2   mental health wellness and AOD counselling
3   Kai on my table
4   Fishing
5   Support with Oranga Tamariki Advocacy
6   Housing pathway with WINZ
7   Deal with personal matters
8   Referral to Owaraika Health services
```

The result I desire is in form of a table below such that has `Abreviation` and `Māori_word` columns:

```
    outcome                                                 Abbreviation     Māori_word             
0   I want to go to DHB                                     DHB      
1   Self Determination and Self-Management Rangatiratanga                    Rangatiratanga
2   mental health wellness and AOD counselling              AOD              
3   Kai on my table                                                          Kai
4   Fishing                                                                  
5   Support with Oranga Tamariki Advocacy                                    Oranga Tamariki
6   Housing pathway with WINZ                               WINZ             
7   Deal with personal matters                                               
8   Referral to Owaraika Health services                                     Owaraika
```

The approach I am using is to extract the ACRONYMS using regular expression and extract the Māori words using nltk module.

I have been able to extract the ACRONYMS using regular expression with this code:

```
pattern = '(\\b[A-Z](?:[\\.&]?[A-Z]){1,7}\\b)'
foo_df['Abbreviation'] = foo_df.outcome.str.extract(pattern)
```

I have been able to extract non-english words from a sentence using the code below:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('words')
from nltk.corpus import words

words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())

sent = "Self Determination and Self-Management Rangatiratanga"
" ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(sent) \
         if not w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha())
```

However, I got an error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` when I tried to iterate the above code over a dataframe. The iteration I tried is below:

```
def no_english(text):
  words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())
  " ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(text['outcome']) \
         if not w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha())

foo_df['Māori_word'] = foo_df.apply(no_english, axis = 1)
print(foo_df)
```

Any help in python3 will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please add the code you tried, and also explain the criteria for a substring/word to be an **abreviation** since `PackNSave` doesn't seem to be **abbreviation**, and also explain `Māori` words.

Comment: It seems to be Natural language processing problem, you have to process the text using libraries like SpaCy.

Comment: I have improved the format of the Data by replacing ```PakNSave``` with proper abbreviation ```DHB```. The idea that I have is to use ```regex``` to extract acronyms and use a suitable ```nlp``` library to extract māori words. Texts that are not english or acronym are māori words.

Comment: I have partially answered my question by extracting the ACRONYMS using regular expression, and have been able to extract Māori words from a sentence using ```nltk``` library. But I got this error ```TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object``` when I iterated this code over a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can't magically tell if a word is English/Māori/abbreviation with a simple short regex. Actually, it is quite likely that some words can be found in multiple categories, so the task itself is not binary (or trinary in this case).

What you want to do is natural language processing, here are some [examples of libraries for language detection in python](https://towardsdatascience.com/4-python-libraries-to-detect-english-and-non-english-language-c82ad3efd430). What you'll get is a probability that the input is in a given language. This is usually ran on full texts but you could apply it to single words.

Another approach is to use Māori and abbreviation dictionaries (=exhaustive/selected lists of words) and craft a function to tell if a word is one of them and assume English otherwise.